# Columns with text (not a table) of different lengths

Tags: multicol

**Hello everyone**

How to create 3 columns of different lengths, without spaces (highlighted in yellow)?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

%%% Работа с русским языком
\usepackage{cmap}                   % поиск в PDF
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}           % кодировка
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         % кодировка исходного текста
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel} % локализация и переносы



%%% Создание maketitle
\author{3Blue1Brown}
\title{Линейная алгебра} 
\date{}


%%% Изменение стиля названия
\makeatletter
\def\@maketitle{%
    \newpage
    \null
    \vskip 2em%
    \begin{center}%
        \let \footnote \thanks
        {\Huge\bfseries\@title \par}%
        \vskip 1.5em%
        {\large
            \lineskip .5em%
            \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
                \@author
            \end{tabular}\par}%
        \vskip 1em%
        {\large \@date}%
    \end{center}%
    \par
    \vskip 1.5em}
\makeatother

\usepackage{multicol}



\begin{document} % Конец преамбулы, начало текста.

    \maketitle

    \begin{multicols}{3}
        [
        \begin{center}
            \section*{Вектора}
        \end{center}
        В разных областях разная формулировка термина вектор.
        ]
        
        \begin{center}
            \textbf{Физика}
        \end{center}
        Вектор - это стрелка в пространстве, которая имеет длину (она зависит от величины прикладываемой силы) и направление.       \vfill\null
        \columnbreak

        \begin{center}
            \textbf{Математика}
        \end{center}
        Вектор - это объект, в котором работает сложение и умножение двух векторов. (Линейная комбинация двух отсканированных векторов)
        \columnbreak
            
        \begin{center}
            \textbf{Информатика}
        \end{center}
        Вектор - список чисел, имеющий размерность и определенный порядок.  
        \vfill\null
        \columnbreak

    \end{multicols}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You may be interested in the `paracol` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\centerline` instead of `\begin{center}` for the titles of the columns.

[image: x]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

%%% Работа с русским языком
\usepackage{cmap}                   % поиск в PDF
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}           % кодировка
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         % кодировка исходного текста
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel} % локализация и переносы
    
%%% Создание maketitle
\author{3Blue1Brown}
\title{Линейная алгебра} 
\date{}
    
%%% Изменение стиля названия
\makeatletter
\def\@maketitle{%
    \newpage
    \null
    \vskip 2em%
    \begin{center}%
        \let \footnote \thanks
        {\Huge\bfseries\@title \par}%
        \vskip 1.5em%
        {\large
            \lineskip .5em%
            \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
                \@author
            \end{tabular}\par}%
        \vskip 1em%
        {\large \@date}%
    \end{center}%
    \par
    \vskip 1.5em}
\makeatother

\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document} % Конец преамбулы, начало текста.
    
    \maketitle
    
    \begin{multicols}{3}
        [
        \begin{center}
            \section*{Вектора}
        \end{center}
        В разных областях разная формулировка термина вектор.
        ]
        \parindent0pt % added <<<<

        \centerline{\textbf{Физика}}% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<          

        Вектор - это стрелка в пространстве, которая имеет длину (она зависит от величины прикладываемой силы) и направление.   
        \vfill\null
        \columnbreak        

        \centerline{\textbf{Математика}}
    
        Вектор - это объект, в котором работает сложение и умножение двух векторов. (Линейная комбинация двух отсканированных векторов)
        \vfill\null
        \columnbreak
        
        \centerline{\textbf{Информатика}}
        
        Вектор - список чисел, имеющий размерность и определенный порядок.  
        \vfill\null
        \columnbreak
        
    \end{multicols}
    
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks very much !